# How to identify whether the method accessing the default value or not

Tags: c#, function, parameters, default-value

I'am having a static method named `myStaticMethod`. Which is defined as follows:

```
 public static void myStaticMethod(string strInputVal="Default")
        {       
            if ("Is accessing Default Value") // how can i define this condition
            {
                //Do something
            }
            else
            {
                //Do some other task
            }
        }
```

Now i am able to call the method in different ways as follows:

```
 myStaticMethod(); // will access default value
 myStaticMethod("Some Value");// will use the passed value
 myStaticMethod("Default"); // Here passing value and default value are same
```

Here my question is How can i identify whether the method is accessing the default value or the value passed through the method call.

If i define the condition like;

```
 if (strInputVal == "Default")
    {
       // do operation here
    }
```

> Which is meaning full for all function call expect
>   `myStaticMethod("Default");` because in this case the method actually
>   accessing the passed value, but my condition will say it is accessing
>   the default value

Comment: There is no way to distinguish `myStaticMethod()` from `myStaticMethod("Default")`, you have to use *method overloading* (create 2 methods: parameterless and one with parameter), don't use parameter with default value in this scenario.

Comment: @Sinatr Write that up as an answer, it's pretty much spot on.

Comment: @Sinatr I've written up an answer based on your comment, I hope you don't mind; I'll remove it if you do.

Comment: @AdrianWragg, you are very kind reputation ninja ;). I don't mind or you would see my answer already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

+1 to @Sinatr I only will add clarification.:

```
public static void myStaticMethod(string strInputVal)
{
    // Do what same part
}

// When you call this method it is 
public static void myStaticMethod()
{
    string strInputVal = "Default";   
    //Do something for default value
    System.Console.WriteLine("I am indetified as called with default value");
    myStaticMethod(strInputVal);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Sinatr in the comments, overloading the method is likely to be the most efficient method. Both overloads can then funnel control into a single internal method indicating whether the default value was used or not:

```
public static void myStaticMethod()
{
    myInternalStaticMethod ("Default", true);
}

public static void myStaticMethod(string inputValue)
{
    myInternalStaticMethod (inputValue, false);
}

private static void myInternalStaticMethod(string inputValue, bool isDefault)
{
    if (isDefault) {
            //Do something
    } else {
            //Do some other task
    }
}
```